# How to grab Xpath query in Googlesheet IMPORTXML function?

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

Trying to grab from a link (https://www.valueresearchonline.com/stocks/1764/infosys-ltd?utm_source=direct-click&utm_medium=stocks&utm_term=&utm_content=Infosys&utm_campaign=vro-search#snapshot)- this is the relevant HTML:

I've made the following query to try and work with the subsequent HTML:

```
Essential Checks
Altman Z-Score   
=IMPORTXML($A$2,"//*[@id='z-score']/div/div[2]/div/div")
```

A2 having the relevant URL.

I think the Xpath is correct there, but not sure why it won't give me the result.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `IMPORTXML` [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en):

> `IMPORTXML` imports data from any of various structured data types including XML, HTML, CSV, TSV, and RSS and ATOM XML feeds.

Therefore, the `=IMPORTXML()` command you are using reads the `HTML` source of the page without any JavaScript code associated with it and without executing it.

So since the website you are trying to `import` the data from is a **dynamic website**, the results you are getting are not the expected ones. In this case, unfortunately, the use of `IMPORTXML()` is not possible.